# Image is not saving in database django

Tags: django, ajax

**form.html**

```
<form>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="name">NAME: </label>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data.name" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="name of product">
                    </td>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="price">PRICE </label>
                        <input type="text" name="price" data-bind="value:$data.price" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="price">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="description">DESCRIPTION: </label>
                        <textarea cols="10" rows="5" name="description" data-bind="value:$data.description" class="form-control" id="description" placeholder="product description"></textarea>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="image">IMAGE: </label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image"  required>
                            
                    </td>
                </tr>
               
                <tr><td><button type="button" id="submit" data-bind="click : save" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button></td></tr>
                 
                    
            </table>
        </form></div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script type="application/javascript" src="static/js/knockout-file-bind.js"></script> -->

         
        <script>
            function getCookie(name) {
              let cookieValue = null;
              if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                  const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                  for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                      const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                      
                      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
              return cookieValue;
          }
          const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); 
        </script>
      
                


     <script>
        var ViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;
            self.save = function () {
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append('image', $('#image').get(0).files[0]);
                formdata.append('name', ko.observable(""));
                formdata.append('price', ko.observable(""));
                formdata.append('description', ko.observable(""));
                console.log(formdata)
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{% url 'addProduct' %}",
                    data: formdata,
                    headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
                    processData: false,                
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (){
                        alert('The post has been created!')
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                });
};
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**views.py**

```
def productform(request):
    return render(request, 'app/product_form.html')

class ProductCreateView(CreateView):
   model = Product
   fields = ['name', 'price', 'description', 'image']
   success_url=reverse_lazy('create-form')

def addProduct(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        product=Product()
        product.name = request.POST['name']
        product.description = request.POST['description']
        product.price = request.POST['price']
        
        if len(request.FILES) != 0:
            if len(product.image) > 0:
                os.remove(product.image.path)
            product.image = request.FILES['image']
        
        product.save()
        
        
        return render(request, 'app/product_form.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'app/product_form.html')




#    def get_success_url(self):
#        return reverse('successlist')



def detail_view(request, id):
    context ={}
    context["data"] = Product.objects.get(id = id)
         
    return render(request, "detail_view.html", context)
```

Image is not saving in database django I don't know what is the issue but image file name is displaying in console.log in ajax. Issue is image is not saving to database
When i try to print(request.FILES) it shows multidict is empty
I have given html code views code please check
Please help me to solve this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked what value does `request.FILES` print ? Also set `contentType: false` in ajax

Comment: I checked it shows multidict is empty

Answer (score 0):

in your form.html try adding

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    # the rest of your code
</form>
```

Comment: I added this in ajax code but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a formdata object in an $.ajax request you must set the data field to that formdata object.
Also all the fields must be in it, append all to fields into it when you're making the ajax request not before.

```
    self.save = function () {

        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('image', $('#image').get(0).files[0]);
        formdata.append('name', ko.observable(""));
        formdata.append('price', ko.observable(""));
        formdata.append('description', ko.observable(""));
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'addProduct' %}",
            data: formdata,
            headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken},
            processData: false,                
            contentType: false,
            success: function (){
                alert('The post has been created!')
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I have edited this code in my project but now image is saving issue is title,price and description is saving as [object Object]

Comment: Please help me to solve this